# Determine timezone from string "2016-09-14T00:00:00.000-07:00/2016-09-15T00:00:00.000-07:00"

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

My code is running with -Duser.timezone=UTC.

I am looking to create an Interval with the correct timezone from strings.
For example:

**"2016-09-14T00:00:00.000-07:00/2016-09-15T07:00:00.000-07:00"**

`Interval.parse(str)` should give me

**[2016-09-14/2016-09-15]** in **PST**.

But that always give me an Interval in UTC instead of PST b/c of -Duser.timezone=UTC option.

The only way I know of to solve this is tedious and involves the following steps:

1. Parse the string
2. Determine Offset
3. Find what timezone that offset corresponds to. 
   (whitelist? or someone has a list already?)
4. Then create a new Interval myself.

Is there a better way?

Comment: you're passing that entire `date/date` string to the parse function? that's only supposed to handle ONE date/time, not figure out which of the two you want. you should split the string into two parts on the `/`, then pass ONE of those resulting values to the parser.

Comment: You cannot map a fixed offset like `-07:00` to a time zone abbreviation like `PST` or to a time zone like `America/Los_Angeles`.  There are too many ambiguities.  Read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  Also, consider that `-07:00` in the United States isn't `PST` at all, but rather `MST`, or `PDT`.

Answer (score -1):

This should get you started:

```
    String dateString = "2016-09-14T00:00:00.000-0700/2016-09-15T07:00:00.000-0700";
    String datesInString[] = dateString.split("/");

    SimpleDateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    outputDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
    Date date0 = inputDateFormat.parse(datesInString[0]);
    Date date1 = inputDateFormat.parse(datesInString[1]);
    String result = outputDateFormat.format(date0) + "/"
            + outputDateFormat.format(date1) + " "
            + outputDateFormat.getTimeZone().getID();
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: This doesn't use JodaTime, and is making a firm assumption that the offsets are indeed PST.  In actuality, they can't be.  They are probably PDT, `America/Los_Angeles`, but a Joda-Time answer is required here.